# Python indent string to JSON

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, string, yaml

In `Python` I have a string in the format:

```
header:
    hello: world
    world: hello
    this:
        is: difficult
    this: 2
```

Which I would like to have converted into `JSON`:

```
{ header: { hello: world, world: hello, this: { is: difficult} }}
```

Is that possible in an efficient way?

I've tried with `yaml.load(str)` but that cannot handle such.

**UPDATE**

I've replaced tabs with spaces, and this makes `yaml` not fail.

My final issue is now that in my original string/object I can have duplicate keys. Not sure how to handle this with `yaml`, but it's random the order, so I would like to preserve all keys, or have the key containing an object as value prioritised above keys containing a simple integer. Make sense, any way to handle this?

Comment: How are you using yaml? I've tried it and it loads exactly as required.

Comment: The desired output is not JSON, because it's missing the quotes. Is that the issue? You can `json.dumps` the dictionary loaded via `yaml.load`, and then replace quotes with empty strings.

Answer (score 0):

YAML works fine for me...

```
test="""header:
    hello: world
    world: hello
    this:
        is: difficult"""

print(test)
```

> 'header:\n    hello: world\n    world: hello\n    this:\n        is: difficult'

```
import yaml
yaml.load(test)
```

> {'header': {'hello': 'world', 'world': 'hello', 'this': {'is': 'difficult'}}}

Comment: I'm getting the error: `yaml.scanner.ScannerError: while scanning for the next token
found character '\t' that cannot start any token` So it seems by string is tab-indent.

Comment: @AlfredBalle Then replace tab characters with a couple of spaces before invoking `yaml.load`

Comment: @L3viathan, do you have tabs between the keys and values? eg `hello:\tworld`, if so you will have to convert the input somehow first. Where is the input coming from? It would probably be easiest to change the output of that.

Comment: Replacing tabs with spaces makes stuff work, but not completely. Please see updated question above.

Comment: Added a bit more context to final issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
import yaml  # pip install pyyaml
import json

yaml_text = '''
header:
    hello: world
    world: hello
    this:
        is: difficult
'''
temp_dict = yaml.load(yaml_text)
json_text = json.dumps(temp_dict)
```

I thought you may want to convert it to a json like string. The above solution works on my machine with Python version 3.7.6 and PyYaml version 5.3.

Comment: OP don't need to change it to ``str``,`json` is ok.